# Ошибка при установке PngQuant

Tags: linux, debian, изображения, apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
git clone git://github.com/pornel/pngquant.git
cd pngquant
./configure
make
```

Пытаюсь я установить `pngquant` на Debian 7 x64, но всё без успешно, система выдает мне невиданную ошибку.

```
gcc -O3 -fno-math-errno -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -std=c99 -I. -DNDEBUG -DUSE_SSE=1 -msse -mfpmath=sse -Wno-unknown-pragmas -I/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include -I/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include -fexcess-precision=fast   -c -o pngquant.o pngquant.c
In file included from pngquant.c:66:0:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h: In function 'fileno':
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:39:17: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h: In function 'fdopen':
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:56:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h: At top level:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:74:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'fwrite' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:97:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'snprintf' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:98:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'vsnprintf' [enabled by default]
In file included from pngquant.c:67:0:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h:39:29: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h:41:29: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'calloc' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h:42:29: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'realloc' [enabled by default]
In file included from pngquant.c:68:0:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:12:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memchr' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:13:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memcmp' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:14:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memcpy' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:16:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memmove' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:17:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memset' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:26:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strcspn' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:30:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strlen' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:32:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strncat' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:34:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strncmp' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:35:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strncpy' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:42:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strspn' [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdint.h:8:0,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/sys/types.h:10,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from pngquant.c:72:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/bitsize/stdint.h:27:0: warning: "__INT64_C" redefined [enabled by default]
pngquant.c:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdint.h:8:0,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/sys/types.h:10,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from pngquant.c:72:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/bitsize/stdint.h:28:0: warning: "__UINT64_C" redefined [enabled by default]
pngquant.c:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from rwpng.h:38:0,
                 from pngquant.c:90:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/png.h:1667:52: warning: 'struct tm' declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/png.h:1667:52: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/png.h:1671:49: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
pngquant.c: In function 'main':
pngquant.c:315:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atof' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
pngquant.c: In function 'write_image':
pngquant.c:791:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'unlink' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
make: *** [pngquant.o] Error 1
```

**UPD:** обновил, что говорит ./configure

```
 Compiler: gcc
     Debug: no
       SSE: yes
    OpenMP: no
    libpng: shared (1.2.44)
      zlib: shared ... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
     lcms2: no
```

**UPD 2:** все решилось удалением папки `/usr/lib/syslinux/`

Comment: а что `./configure` говорит?

Comment: Странно, откуда там взялся include из `syslinux`... По логике, `pngquant` должен собирать с `-I/usr/include/libpng16`.

Comment: @approximatenumber, обновил пост

Comment: Кстати, почему из исходных текстов решили собрать? Для debian ведь [есть пакет](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/pngquant)

Comment: если устанавливать `apt-get install pngquant` установится версия 1.0, которая ничего не сжимает да и не работает. Хотя так только на `Debian 7`, на 8й версии ставится 2+ версия `pngquant`, вот https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/pngquant

Comment: А просто поставить [deb-пакет](https://pkgs.org/debian-jessie/debian-main-amd64/pngquant_2.3.0-1_amd64.deb.html)?

Comment: вот так не ставится `sudo dpkg -i pngquant_2.3.0-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Без вывода ошибок сложно разобраться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40294/discussion-between-emtecif-and-approximatenumber).